# Generalized eigenvectors of a hermitian matrix can be orthonormal or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A = A^{\star} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and some of its eigenvalues are repeated. In this case, is it possible to construct a full set of orthonormal eigenvectors for the matrix $A$ inspite of having repeated eigenvalues?

Comment: An $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix possesses a full set of eigenvectors, which can be chosen to be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: Could you please suggest a reference or book?

Answer (score 1):

Any generalized eigenvector of a hermitian matrix is actually an eigenvector.  Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal, and for any eigenvalue you can choose an orthonormal basis of the corresponding eigenspace.  So yes.

This is a lot of the content of finite dimensional spectral theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case